# Angular with Dart

Tags: angular, dart

Is it possible to use the Typescript version of Angular with Dart?
I can't find any sort of bindings.

I understand Angular Dart is there, but you might consider this question as purely technical (and it still lacks components).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Dart Angular and TypeScript Angular on the same page if the parts don't overlap, but they won't recognize each other and won't work together in any Angular-specific way.

You can use Dart-JS-Interop to communicate between TypeScript and Dart but without any specific Angular support.

So basically the answer is **no**.

Comment: Thanks Gunter! I was looking at https://github.com/polymer-dart/dart2ts
Hope this project does some progress.

Comment: I think you're wasting your time. Either use Dart or TS and forget about combining. That's what the Angular team did because it's too complicated.

Comment: Perhaps interesting additional context: Angular (Dart and TS) depend a lot on code generation and tree-shaking. When the app is compiled there isn't much left in the build output that allows the output to be recognized as Angular application, it's just HTML, JS, and CSS. To make Dart and TS work together they would need to be compiled to a single application in a single step. Otherwise it wouldn't be possible to know what parts of the code can be stripped by tree-shaking.